# No module named _sqlite3 with Django on Google App Engine SDK 1.8 - Windows 7

Tags: django, sqlite

All the answers that i searched for relating to this error on StackFlow are for Linux systems.
I do not understand. Can some one suggest the solution for Windows System.
I do not get any error when i type import **sqlite** in **python** shell but when i browse my application using **GAE SDK..** this error comes in the log file

```
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named _sqlite3
```

Comment: Sounds like it can't find the SQLite native bindings. Is SQLite even supported on GAE? This page might help: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/?hl=sv

Comment: Articles that i have read suggests that it is supported.